# ag-grid object nested array

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Hi guys I have array as one of the column data and I would like to display it using ag-grid may I know what are my options

```
https://stackblitz.com/github/snehalp29/ag-grid-demo

columnDefs = [
    { field: 'freLoanId' , checkboxSelection: true,  headerCheckboxSelection: true},
    { field: 'loanAmt' },
    { field: 'interestRate'},
    {field: 'loanInterestRateStructureType'},
    {field: 'loanSecuritizationEligibilityInd'},
    {field: 'properties.pptyName'}
  ];
```

I tried above code but its not working

Answer (score 3):

You can't have nested fields in column definition `field` attribute as that is an attribute that is used by agGrid internally and not related to your row object that you are passing in `rowData`.

The way to do this is to use a `cellRenderer` or a `valueGetter` method while giving your `field` attribute a proper name.

so instead of :

```
{field: 'properties.pptyName'}
```

try

```
{
  field: 'pptyName',
  valueGetter: (params) => {
    return params.value.properties.pptyName;
  }
}
```

this would work if you pass the entire `properties` object to the `rowData` attribute `pptyName`.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Instead of params.value I found params.data though.

Comment: Just because I stumbled over this reply - seems like ag-grid introduced the dot notation with version 28 - https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/28.0.0/javascript-data-grid/column-definitions/#accessing-row-data-values ( in ver. 27 this paragraph does not exist - https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/27.0.0/javascript-data-grid/column-definitions/)

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```
columnDefs = [
    {
      field: "freLoanId",
      checkboxSelection: true,
      headerCheckboxSelection: true
    },
    { field: "loanAmt" },
    { field: "interestRate" },
    { field: "loanInterestRateStructureType" },
    { field: "loanSecuritizationEligibilityInd" },
    {
      field: "pptyName (or custom name)",
      valueGetter: params => {
        console.log(params.data.properties[0].pptyName);
        return params.data.properties[0].pptyName;
      }
    }
  ];
```

Check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-a9uxcv?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/value-setters/